# filling result of data adapter to my own data set?

Tags: c#, dataset

before start my question I need to mention I'm c++ programmer not c#, so maybe my code syntax seems wrong. I'm amateur and need improvement!;)

I have a question (maybe it's an idea instead of question) about working with result of data adapter output. 
let's take a look at theses lines:

```
public DataSet CollectData()
{
    DataSet result = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.StoredProc1", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        IDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        adapter.Fill(result);/// filling a dataset

        return result;
    }
}
```

as you see this function fill a data set and return it.
Anywhere that I want to use this object I should loop through it like this:

```
    DataSet dataSet = DataObj.CollectData(); /// above function!

    string token;
    string lemma;
    foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        token = ((string)row["Token"]);
        lemma = ((string)row["Lemma"]);
        ...

        //// TODO: ex. write to file 
    }
```

but, I have a class that it demonstrate this stored objects.

a class like this:

```
public class Lexeme
{
private int tokenId = -1;
private string token;
private string lemma;
/// some get and set functions!
}
```

as you see this class holds an object (it's something like a wrapper for stored object inside of database tables)

So I want to know is there anyway to return a list of this object (Lexeme here) instead of dataset? I mean something with efficient memory usage. because i work with huge amount of data.

for example something like this:

```
public MYDATASET CollectData()
{
    MYDATASET result = new MYDATASET ();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.StoredProc1", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        IDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        adapter.Fill(result);/// filling a dataset

        return result;
    }
}
```

dataset can be inherited?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Typed Dataset` instead of your own object. This allows you to fill a dataset easily, but also have strongly typed columns and the ability to access each property easily within a row. Go to the `Add New Item` window of Visual Studio and add a Dataset. Add a new table using the designer, and add the columns that are being returned from your sql query. Go to the properties window on each column and specify the type (int, string, etc).

From there, when you're loading the dataset, create a new object of your dataset type, and fill it like you were before:

```
public MyTypedDataset GetMyDataSet()
{
    MyTypedDataset ds = new MyTypedDataset();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.StoredProc1", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        IDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        adapter.Fill(ds.Table1);

        return result;
    }
}
```

With a typed dataset there is a property for each table item you created in the designer. (By default I believe it is named `Table1`?)

Now, when accessing your data, you can do

```
MyTypedDataset ds = GetMyDataSet();
string myToken = ds.Table1.Rows[0].Token;
string myLemma = ds.Table1.Rows[0].Lemma;
```

Or in a foreach:

```
MyTypedDataset ds = GetMyDataSet();
foreach(var row in ds.Table1)
{
    string myToken = row.Token;
    string myLemma = row.Lemma;
}
```

This isn't quite as good as getting a list of your object back, but it's almost there. If you want a list of your own object, you'll most likely need to use an `Object Relational Mapper`, such as Entity Framework or NHibernate.

Comment: god bless you, I was looking for this exactly...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320714